# Passing same parameters from Main report to subreport(same procedure)

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I'm having a problem setting the parameters of a subreport.
Both reports (main and subreport) use same stored procedures.  Both procedures have the exact same parameters (named the same as well). 
When i tried it shows main report parameter and sub report parameter.(id. how can i pass main report parameter value only(crystal Report2008))

Comment: Do you mean that main report and subreport run for different values of parameters, while you would like them to run for the same values?

Comment: I would like to run for the same value(main report & sub report). i.e like to give value for main report only  not for sub report again

Comment: You have to edit the Subreport Links. From there you can match every parameter of subreport with one of main report. Once you do that the subreport will run every time for the same values of the main's report, you will not have to give additional values. Do you know how to change Subreport Links?